# Why won't my PHP script work?

Tags: php

I have a script that reports the following error:

> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: Access
>   denied for user 'admin'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) in
>   C:\wamp\www\bits\includes\connect.inc.php
>   on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: l_error in
>   C:\wamp\www\bits\includes\connect.inc.php
>   on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined variable:
>   l_cannotconnecttodatabase in
>   C:\wamp\www\bits\includes\connect.inc.php
>   on line 12

Why would this be?

Comment: I think there's nothing we can say that the error messages do not already.

Comment: You will need to formulate a clearer question with more precise information, if you don't want to be closed. you didn't tell us what bits is and what your configuration looks like.

Comment: my bits is 2.04 And my question is how i make this script work  simple as that

Comment: Pay someone to fix your script for you.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql user or password are incorrect. You need to set them in install script to correct values

Comment: where i can search for user and password? i have to creat a data base with the same user and password that are in the script?

Comment: 1. if you installed mysql server yourself then you should know root password, if not turn to the person who did. 2. it depends on install script, sometimes you just pass root password and script creates user and database by itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the wrong password. Make sure mysql is installed and that whatever you are trying to install if configured to use the password you set for mysql.

Comment: ?? on my panel from wamp in the section of phpmyadmin i have created a data base ... but when i put http://localhost/bits/install.php it appear that

Comment: It sounds like your mysql is definitely working normally. If you didn't change the default, I think the username is root and there is no password, but you might want to double check that since I havent used windows in a while. Your install script is using the user name "admin". Figure out which user name and password combo you use to log into php myadmin and then make sure those values are used in the configuration of the script you are trying to install. Also, if you tell us what you are tying to install we might be able to offer better advice.

Comment: i am trying to install a bitsvideoscript

Comment: Okay, thats a start. Do you know what your mysql username and password are?

Comment: just a sec.. i will explain how i do it ..  ok ?

Comment: 1) Create a database in your hosting control panel.
2) Open the file includes/db.conf.php and change the first lines with your site data.
3) Open the file admin/license.php and change where it says pasteyourlicensehere with your license.
4) Upload all the files.
5) Chmod the folders thumbs, rss, cache, and files to 777
6) Go to http://www.yoursite.com/install.php (replace yoursite with your actual domain)
7) Write your desired administrator user name and password and submit.
.........

Comment: 1) i have made from phpmyadmin a data base called myq_db_bits

Comment: 2) i go in includes/db.conf.php and i have change that.. <?php //database config

$db_server = "localhost";   //database server location
$db_type = "mysql";   //mysql, pgsql, oracle, etc..
$db_db  = "my_db_bits";   //database to use
$db_username = "admin";   //username for $db_db
$db_password = "demo";       //database password
$site="http://www.mysite.com/";  //your site url
$sitetitle="Chat tube";  //yo //your site name

Comment: These lines are probably wrong:  $db_username = "admin";  //username for $db_db $db_password = "demo";. If you have default mysql settings then change them to:  $db_username = "root";  //username for $db_db $db_password = ""; If that doesn't work then find out what your mysql username and password is and use enter those. Good luck.

Comment: 3) on admin/lincense.php i have this <?
$license="js3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdsghtg6c3gpojxfs ";
?>
4)----------- 5)i dont know how to put a 777 permision

Comment: If you have windows you can't set file permissions. Those instructions are for running the script on a presumably linux server.

Comment: ok.. so i can not do this script work?

Comment: The script will work fine on windows.. just ignore the file permissions instructions

Comment: ok.. but how i will make this work

Comment: I already explained it. I even told you which lines to edit. If you can't figure it out from there you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to give you a solution based on the information you supplied, but obviously you're trying to install a system that uses mysql and therefore requires credentials to be able to connect to the database management system.

You should refer to installation manual of the system in question to see where these credentials must be specified in order for installation to proceed.

EDIT: It appears that you will need to create a database and user before you can actually specify them for the bits script. You should have administrator password from the moment you installed mysql (or ask someone who did), and you can then use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) to administer more databases and users. Keep in mind that the database user and all user accounts for your script will most likely be completely different. MySQL user to work with the database in its entirety, whereas user accounts are used to distinguish between the people accessing your scripts.